# Make decorator with PyFunctionObject as input

Tags: cython

I would like to create a c function (cdef public) for a simple Python decorator. For example:

```
cdef public object WrapCPythonPyFunctionObject(int wrapper_id, object func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("enter wrapper")
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("exit wrapper")
        return result
    return <object>wrapper
```

The input `object func` and output `object` both interface with my C/Python API code, and are expected to be PyFunctionObject * types. As far as I'm aware, this should work, but it [segmentation faults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) somewhere in Cython code when I try it out. Is something like this possible? The closest I can find to doing this is [Cython's typecasting feature](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#type-casting), but I am not sure this does what I want.

Comment: A `PyFunctionObject` *is* a proper Python function. It's just the data structure used to store a Python function. I'm really puzzled by what you're trying to do here.

Comment: The PyFunctionObject * being passed in and out of the function come from some C/Python API code I have. I'm simply trying to use cython to make it easier to decorator the input. However, when I run the rough example I have above it segfaults somewhere in cython code, which I have no clue how to debug

Comment: @DavidW I've updated the question in hopes to clarify the issue.

Comment: Your problem may be the output. That will probably be a `CyFunction` object rather than a `PyFunctionObject` since it's implemented in Cython. So if your C API calls are really relying on an exact `PyFunctionObject` you'll probably crash

Comment: If you need an actual `PyFunctionObject` from Cython you need to define wrapper in an `exec` call (so it comes from the Python interpreter). That may defeat the point of using Cython though. Or it might be fine for what you need.

Comment: The PyFunctionObject vs CyFunction type incompatibility makes sense. Could you be more explicit on how you envision `exec` resolving this?

Comment: I've posted it as an answer just because there aren't enough characters to give a useful version in a comment. It's a bit of a guess though so may still be missing the point.

Answer (score 0):

Just filling out what was discussed in the comments a bit more:

It sounds like the issue may be that the value returned from this function is passed to something that expects a `PyFunctionObject` (which is what Python uses to represent functions defined in Python). However Cython functions are implemented in C and so are either Cython's own `CyFunction` or a `PyCFunctionObject` (depending on the exact compiler directives).

Assuming that this is the case, and that needing a `PyFunctionObject` is a hard requirement, then it might be possible to use either `eval` or `exec` from within Cython to call the Python interpreter and generate a real `PyFunctionObject`:

```py
cdef public object WrapCPythonPyFunctionObject(int wrapper_id, object func):
    locals_dict = {'func', func}
    exec("""
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    print("enter wrapper")
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    print("exit wrapper")
    return result
    """, {}, locals_dict)
    return locals_dict['wrapper']
```

That isn't great if you want to use Cython language features inside wrapper. In that case you'd define `wrapper` in Cython, and then write an even thinner wrapper around it:

```py
cdef public object WrapCPythonPyFunctionObject(int wrapper_id, object func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("enter wrapper")
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("exit wrapper")
        return result
    return eval("lambda *args, **kwds: wrapper(*args, **kwds)")
```

It's possible I'm still not understanding the ultimate goal here, so maybe this isn't helpful. But hopefully it is.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, and both really cool ideas! seems like you have the right understanding of the issue, and yes, PyFunctionObject * input and output is a hard requirement. i'll try these out tomorrow along with some tweaking if needed and see if i cant get it working